# How to show examples of work as a requirement to gain a freelancing project?

Tags: career-development, freelancing

I recently applied for a freelancing project. The employer contacted me saying:

> Could you please send examples of your work with SDK and XML files?

What am I supposed to provide him? A piece of my code or a video of my project or something else?  What should one provide a potential client or a potential employer when they ask for samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably just want to see your style of coding. How do you write your code, do you use inline comments, consistency in naming variables/methods etc., and maybe, if possible from a sample, see if your level is what they want/expect it to be.

I wouldn't sweat to much about it. Just send them some code you are proud to 'show off with' that gives a clear image of what your coding style is.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they want to see some sample code. The wording is strange, maybe that request originates from an HR department not from a software developer. Anyway, they are asking for a small sample of compilable code.

If you have code that you can disclose for example a private project working with XML and some SDK, you can send that. It would also be a welcome opportunity to ask them what tools they use so you can send a sample best suited to their compiler/language/toolchain.